# Resize elementary OS partition to make a space for Windows 11

Tags: system-installation, disk-management

I have installed Elementary OS 7.1 Horus and now I would like if possible install dual boot Windows so I tried via Elementary OS live USB to resize (decrease) size via gparted of partition for home but without success. Why is resizing not allowed? I see something like lock on /home partition.